# Using ValueMember for a combobox or a Listbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a table in SQL Server :
its name is `[dbo].[Family_Tree]`

```
ID  NodeName
1   John
2   George
3   Mike
4   Sandra
5   Jasmine
6   Lucy
```

---

I have created a Vb.net Application where I want to present these names in a Combobox or a listbox

Here's the code to fill the Listbox:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnString)
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    Dim Adp As New SqlDataAdapter

    With Adp
        .SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("Select NodeName , ID From Family_tree", conn)
        .Fill(DT)
    End With


    With ListBox1
        .DataSource = DT
        .DisplayMember = "NodeName"
        .ValueMember = "ID"
    End With

End Using
```

Names are Displayed and nothing is wrong with them , what I want is when I choose any name the listbox returns its corresponding ID `.ValueMember = "ID"`
, I tested it in a msgbox `MsgBox(ListBox1.ValueMember)` it always Returns ID , so how can I make it understand that this is a Column not a String ?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ListBox.SelectedItem`, f.e. in it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim curItem As DataRowView = TryCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    If curItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim id = curItem.Row.Field(Of Int32)("ID")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: oh thanks that one worked , but does ValueMember work too ? I mean like in treeview you assign a tag for every node like its ID , is ValueMember like the Combobox/Listbox Tag ?

Comment: @will: the `ValueMember` property is just used to specify the property of the `DataSource` that is used to identify a record, so like `ID` in your example. It is not to be used to get the actual ID. Therefore use my approach or the `SelectedValue`  as Steve has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Value of the current displayed item in the listbox you write

```
if ListBox1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim v = Convert.ToInt32(ListBox1.SelectedValue)
    .......
```

[ListControl.SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the
>   ValueMember property.